# Why is this claiming that i dont have brackets []

Tags: java, arrays, csv, arraylist

I can't figure out what's wrong here. my code is supposed to check how many times a state specific appears in a 1 column csv file. I'm trying to avoid having a separate counter for each individual state

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class csvtxt {

   public static void main(String a[]){
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      String strLine = "";
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
      try {
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\dbb38\\Downloads\\customers_export_1111 - customers_export_1.csv"));
         while (strLine != null)
         {
            strLine = br.readLine();
            if (strLine==null)
               break;
            sb.append(strLine);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            list.add(strLine);
         }
         String[] state = new String[]{"Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"};
         String[] state1 = new String[]{"Alabama1", "Alaska1", "Arizona1", "Arkansas1", "California1", "Colorado1", "Connecticut1", "Delaware1", "Florida1", "Georgia1", "Hawaii1", "Idaho1", "Illinois1", "Indiana1", "Iowa1", "Kansas1", "Kentucky1", "Louisiana1", "Maine1", "Maryland1", "Massachusetts1", "Michigan1", "Minnesota1", "Mississippi1", "Missouri1", "Montana1", "Nebraska1", "Nevada1", "New Hampshire1", "New Jersey1", "New Mexico1", "New York1", "North Carolina1", "North Dakota1", "Ohio1", "Oklahoma1", "Oregon1", "Pennsylvania1", "Rhode Island1", "South Carolina1", "South Dakota1", "Tennessee1", "Texas1", "Utah1", "Vermont1", "Virginia1", "Washington1", "West Virginia1", "Wisconsin1", "Wyoming1"};
         for(i=0; i<list.size; i++)
         {
            String wordToSearchFor = state[i];
            String[] state1[i] = 0;
            for(String state2 : list)
            {
               if(state2.equals(wordToSearchFor)) 
               {
                  state1[i]++;
               }
         }
         System.out.println(state[i] + "="  + "["+ Vermont +"]");
         }
         //
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
         br.close();
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.err.println("File not found");
      } catch (IOException e) {
         System.err.println("Unable to read the file.");
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the error im getting. I'm not sure why i'm receiving it and i've tried to replace it and put it back in.

```
csvtxt.java:31: error: ']' expected
            String[] state1[i] = 0;
                            ^
csvtxt.java:31: error: illegal start of expression
            String[] state1[i] = 0;
                             ^
2 errors
```

Comment: Wouldn't `state1[i] = 0` be more accurate?  You don't need to provide a definition for a object which has already been defined

Comment: I'll also add that, once you've resolved the issue _currently_  highlighting as an error; `state1[i]++;` is _also_ going to cause one.  There is no `++` operator for `String`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of backwards compatibility with C/C++ of the beginning of java.
The array declaration:

```
int[] x;
```

can be written in C-style:

```
int x[];
```

So in your case a mix was expected:

```
String[] state1[] = ...;
```

aka

```
String[][] state1 = ...;
```

standing for a two dimension String matrix/array. The error was on encountering an `i` in `[i]` instead of just `[]`.

What you intended to do was assigning to an element.

```
    int[] state1 = new int[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size; i++) {
        // state1[i] = 0; // Not needed already 0.
        String wordToSearchFor = state[i];
        for (String state2 : list) {
            if (state2.equals(wordToSearchFor)) {
                state1[i]++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(state[i] + "="  + "["+ Vermont +"]");
    }
```

Comment: What does the first line do?

Comment: `int[] state1` declares an array of ints. `new int[10]` creates an array of 10 ints, all zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

```
        String[] state1[i] = 0;
```

This isn't correct java syntax, instead do it like this:

```
String[] arrayName = {"0"};
```

Or if you want to set everything in state1 to 0, do it like this:

```
state1[i] = {"0"};
```

I don't know if you mean to have 0 there as a value if so, you'd probably want to use an int[] array.